# Transfer data storage from Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-context

Project description: I have a site on each page of which there is a SideBar with filters

Implementation: I created a FiltersContextWrapper and placed it in App.js. To remember the state of the filters (SideBar is open or not, the filters themselves are open or not, and the filter values themselves) on any page of the site.

Problem: When I began to dive into the study further, I realized that, It's very bad practice to pass functions in context. Use functions from context makes code unpredictable.
And I need to store state of filters and work with it, instead of changing component state from the outside.

That is: I hide all the actions on the basis of which the data changes in the context. It is almost impossible to track where the data will change from. And in general, functions should not lie in the state manager, including in the context.
Actually, in the state manager, I need to store the state of the filters themselves, and change them with functions that will be tied to the corresponding store.

I believe that a very good library for this is recoil. And I would like to ask the community how can I translate my code to this library

All code is from the link I pasted above. Here (since this is required by the stackoverflow rules) I will present the code FiltersContextWrapper

```
 export default function FiltersContextWrapper({ children }) {
  const [hideSidebar, setHideSidebar] = useState(true);

  const [filterRequestURLOpen, setFilterRequestURLOpen] = useState(false);
  const [filterDateTimeOpen, setFilterDateTimeOpen] = useState(false);

  const start = moment("2023-01-01").set({ hour: "00", minute: "00" });
  const end = moment(moment().startOf("day"))
    .add(1, "days")
    .subtract(1, "seconds");
  const [time, setTime] = useState({ start, end });
  const resetDate = () => {
    setTime({
      start,
      end
    });
  };

  const resetAll = () => {
    setTime({
      start,
      end
    });
  };

  return (
    <filtersContext.Provider
      value={{
        hideSidebar,
        setHideSidebar,
        filterRequestURLOpen,
        setFilterRequestURLOpen,
        filterDateTimeOpen,
        setFilterDateTimeOpen,
        time,
        setTime,
        resetDate,
        resetAll
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </filtersContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const filtersContext = createContext({
  hideSidebar: false,
  setHideSidebar: () => {},
  filterRequestURLOpen: false,
  setFilterRequestURLOpen: () => {},
  filterDateTimeOpen: false,
  setFilterDateTimeOpen: () => {},
  time: false,
  setTime: () => {},
  resetDate: () => {},
  resetAll: () => {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to use an external library (or at least you could achieve similar results without it) for the feature you want to implement.
Please, check these docs out.

https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context

If you wish, I can help you more with refactoring your real app, so don't be shy to ask questions

Comment: Could you fix your sandbox so it will show any route as an example? 
Since RN it's just empty. Also, maybe let's just have a pair programming session, since a lot of your code looks messy :(

Comment: First sentence meant how can I see what is code is trying to accomplish, if HTML is empty?  I changed the showFilters default state to true, but code simply didn't work. I can write code for you or with you, but sent me a diagram/requirements for the  functionality. Since currently functionality is not "wrong written", it's simply not working at all